# How to avoid this java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have to make an app in an Android. I have succeeded in debugging a few bugs but I don't understand this one :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.bookapp, PID: 7450  
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' 
on a null object reference
```

I can notice that Android Studio put an orange background to alert me that some parts of my code may produce java.lang.NullPointerException, but I don't see what to change to avoid that and I don't even see why this error happens when I run my app.

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** find the button view, set an onclick listener on it, define & execute the bookListAsyncTask */
    Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BookListAsyncTask bookListAsyncTask = new BookListAsyncTask();
            bookListAsyncTask.execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * define the URL
 */
public String makeUrl() {
    EditText searchBookEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);
    String searchBook = searchBookEditText.getText().toString();
    String searchBookModified = searchBook.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    final String REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchBookModified + "&maxResults=3&printType=books";
    return REQUEST_URL;
}

private class BookListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<Book>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Book> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // Create URL object
        URL url = createUrl(makeUrl());

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = "";
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create an ArrayList<Book> object
        ArrayList<Book> allBooks = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);

        return allBooks;
    }

    /**
     * Update the screen with the given books (which was the result of the
     * {@link BookListAsyncTask}).
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Book> allBooks) {
        if (allBooks == null) {
            return;
        }
        BookAdapter bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this, allBooks);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error with creating URL", exception);
            return null;
        }
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
     */
    private String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.connect();
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                jsonResponse = "";
                Log.e("MainActivity", "error response code" + String.valueOf(responseCode));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the exception
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results", e);

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // function must handle java.io.IOException here
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
     * whole JSON response from the server.
     */
    private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a book ArrayList
     */
    public ArrayList<Book> extractFeatureFromJson(String bookJSON) {

        ArrayList<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
            JSONArray items = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

            // If there are results in the features array
            if (items.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
                // Parse the JSON and fill the allBooks ArrayList)
                {
                    JSONObject currentBook = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject currentVolumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                    String currentTitle = currentVolumeInfo.getString("title");
                    String currentFirstAuthor = "Author Unknown";
                    Book book = new Book(currentTitle, currentFirstAuthor);
                    allBooks.add(book);
                }

                return allBooks;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

    public BookAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0, books);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
        }

        Book currentBook = getItem(position);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
        title.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

        TextView author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author_text_view);
        author.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
}
```

and the book class, I modified a bit the get methods but it didn't help :

```
public class Book {

private String mTitle;
private String mAuthor;

public Book(String title, String author){
    mTitle = title;
    mAuthor = author;
}

public String getTitle(){
    if (mTitle == null){
        return mTitle = "";}
    else {return mTitle;}}
public String getAuthor(){
    if (mAuthor == null){
        return mAuthor = "";
    } else {return mAuthor;}}
}
```

Do you see what's wrong ?

Comment: right above author.setText(...) is called.

Comment: For some reason title or book is null. Check that your xml has the ids as such variable names.

Comment: tell the line where you are getting exception

Comment: @John3136 there are plenty of dupes of this around but this is a little different than that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the lines

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
TextView author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author_text_view);
```

to

```
TextView title = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);   
TextView author = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.author_text_view);



 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
            }

            Book currentBook = getItem(position);

            TextView title = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
            title.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

            TextView author = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.author_text_view);
            author.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());

            return listItemView;
        }
```

Comment: Hope the solution worked for you.. Please accept the answer..

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your answers. Sonia I changed the findViewById by listItemView.findViewById as you advised and it works now. Thank you ! Can you explain me why it works ? I don't really understand it, my title and author textview can still be null by there is no more NullPointerException alert there.

Comment: This link will be useful. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Comment: @Alex9494 It appears that `BookAdapter` is an inner class of `MainActivity`. When you call `findViewById()` in `BookAdapter`, you are actually calling this method on the containing `MainActivity` object. Since the `MainActivity` does not have any views with the given id, `findViewById()` returns `null`. Even if it already had a view with the given id, `findViewById()` would only return a reference to the first one it finds.